# Matlab: regexp - how to use the command

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to have the value of **$_Wk_leer_Ixx** but to get the value i have to do a short calculation.

My Code (wrong):

```
content = fileread( 'Wk.subvars' ) ;
match = regexp( content, '(?<=\$_Wk_leer_m,\s+str\s*=\s*''\s*)[^\s'']+', 'match' ) ;
Wk1_leer_m = str2double( match ) ;
match = regexp( content, '(?<=\$_Wk_leer_Ixx,\s+str\s*=\s*''\s*)[^\s'']+', 'match' ) ;
Wk_leer_Ixx = str2double( match ) ;
```

**Missing steps:**

1. `str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_leer_m * 2.2 ' )` -> I have to trigger out the
   variable name after `$G_Wk.` -> `$_Wk_leer_m`
2. and the number after `*` sign  ..... -> `2.2`

after that i am able to do the calculation. (the value of **Wk_leer_m** i have)

**Input:**

```
!file.version=1.3! 
! Wagenkas

subvargroup.begin ($G_Wk)   
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_m,                                     str = ' 15601 ' )               ! [kg] Wagenkasten leer  
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_CoG_x,                                 str = ' 0.019 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_CoG_y,                                 str = '-0.007 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_CoG_z,                                 str = ' 1.644 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_Ixx,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_leer_m * 111 ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_Iyy,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_leer_m * 222  ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_leer_Izz,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_leer_m * 333  ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_m,                              str = ' 27660 ' )               ! [kg] Wagenkasten betrieblich
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_CoG_x,                          str = ' 0.0107' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_CoG_y,                          str = '-0.0039 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_CoG_z,                          str = ' 1.7608 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_Ixx,                            str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_betrieblich_m * 444 ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_Iyy,                            str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_betrieblich_m * 555  ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_betrieblich_Izz,                            str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_betrieblich_m * 666 ' )     
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_m,                                     str = ' 33690 ' )               ! [kg] Wagenkasten voll beladen  
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_CoG_x,                                 str = ' 0.0088 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_CoG_y,                                 str = '-0.0032 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_CoG_z,                                 str = ' 1.788 ' ) 
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_Ixx,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_voll_m * 777 ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_Iyy,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_voll_m * 888  ' )
  subvar(      $_Wk_voll_Izz,                                   str = ' $G_Wk.$_Wk_voll_m * 999  ' ) 
subvargroup.end   ($G_Wk)
```

Comment: What's the desired output here?

Comment: Try `match = regexp( content, '\$_Wk_leer_m,\s+str\s*=\s*''\s*([^\s'']+)', 'match', 'tokens')`, and for the second, `match = regexp( content, \$_Wk_leer_Ixx,\s+str\s*=\s*''\s*[^\s'']+\s*\*\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', 'match', 'tokens')`

Comment: it does not work ... :/